# Perform a Windows 7 search & display files with identical names but different integer value at end of each?

Tags: windows-7, search, query

Lets say I have the files:
doc01, doc02, doc03, doc04...doc64

Is there a query I can enter in a normal windows 7 search box, to pull up all these ten files? Also note they they usually have the same file extension.

The reason I'm hopeful this can be done is because in a Linux terminal if I wanted to create these multiple files at once I would do:

```
$ touch doc{01..64}.docx
```

Comment: Which search box are you referring to? The start menu? Explorer? Some other search box?

Comment: Explorer's search box

Answer (score 0):

For your original question, use a query with wildcards, e.g.

> filename:doc*

If you need to search based on a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), use Windows CMD regex utility [findstr](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr). For example, to find all files in the range *doc01* through *doc59*

> dir /b | findstr /i "doc[0-5][0-9]"

Modify this for your needs.

Comment: some of them contain string values after 'doc'; I don't want these to appear. Just those with the interger between 00-99 at the end.